# How to add end screen with YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to edit parameters for end screen while upload a video, but I don't see anything in the document of the API.

It is possible edit end screen through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet supported as of this moment. You're trying to turn [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) into a video editor which is currently out of its scope.

Comment: How does tubebuddy do it? They are a chrome extension which lets user copy card details from any video and paste it to one or more videos in a channel.

Comment: No, that's not what video editing is. The end screen is a piece of data that controls standard YouTube functionality being overlaid on the existing video, just like watermarks and captions are. The video is not changed at all, so this is not editing. It is a perfectly feasible feature to have in a data API - you say "I want the Subscribe button and 1 Playlist template to appear 5 seconds from the end of the video." It's exactly the kind of thing that lends itself to being done in batches.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little bit of research and found something, YouTube allows to send the endscreen template but with a special parameter like "onBehalfOfUser" or sort of and with a special format, but they are validating because there is a NOTE: this is only for youtube partners. So we can assume that tubebuddy it is a youtube partner and it is allowed to use this, probably they sent new endpoints too.

Unfortunately for us, common users, it's not possible and probably won't be ever.

Answer (score -1):

There is no public API available currently, but there is a way to access that special API. You need to apply here https://servicesdirectory.withyoutube.com and apply to Become a Provider. Once approved, this would give you access to that additional API.