# YouTubePlayerView Android - Display End Screens

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I wish to display endscreen associated with the YouTube video in my app. So how to configure YouTubePlayerView to display end screens in Android app. Below is the code used to play YouTube video in my app

```
youTubePlayerView.initialize(new Keys().YTKey(), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored)
        {
            // Defining player
            player = youTubePlayer;

            // Setting flag for the player to play video in fullscreen mode when switched to landscaper orientation
            player.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);

            // Checking whether video is restored or not
            if (!wasRestored)
            {
                // If not restored load video
                player.loadVideo(videoId);
                player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
            }
            else
            {
                // Else play the restored video
                player.play();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed to Initialize Player", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @Jacque Edited my question. Pls do have a look

Comment: Sorry. After actually [looking around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792678/how-to-add-end-screen-with-youtube-data-api), it seems this is still not possible.